# How do I find remaining trigonometic function if $\cos(x)$ is negative?

Tags: trigonometry

What is the mistake in my method because the correct value of $\sin(x)$ is $-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$?

[image: trigonometric_equation_solution_attempt]

Comment: Note that $$1 - \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 = 1 - \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 = 1 - \frac{1}{4} = \frac{3}{4}$$

Comment: @N.F.Taussig i didn't get anything , I'm new here so can you just make it simple because i cannot understand with all those characters

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig can you add it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake when you obtained 
$$1 - \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 = 1 + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$$
However, since 
$$\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$$
the sign of the squared term should not have changed.  You should have obtained
\begin{align*}
\sin^2x & = 1 - \cos^2x\\
        & = 1 - \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\\
        & = 1 - \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\\
        & = 1 - \frac{1}{4}\\
        & = \frac{3}{4}
\end{align*}
Taking square roots yields
$$|\sin x| = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
Hence, 
$$\sin x = \pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Comment: I understood like this, is this correct ? -1/2 x-1/2 = +1/4. As (-1/2)^2.

Comment: @user75648  That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was when you went from $1 - (-1/2)^2$ to $1 + (1/2)^2$. They are not equivalent; in particular, the first one is equal to $1 - (1/2)^2$. Note that it's still subtraction.